# Why does jslint require that `getComputedStyle()` has a window. prefix?

Tags: window, jslint

At the same time it does not require `setInterval()`.  I found this to be inconsistent as both are found on the global window variable.

Below is the function that I ran through the linter:

```
// peaking animation
Pub.peakOut = function (elem, offset, delay, callback) {
    var privates = {};

    // constants initialization
    privates.RADIX = 10;
    privates.GRAN_TIME = 15;
    privates.GRAN_DIST = 1;
    privates.UNITS = 'px';

    // privates initialization
    privates.el = elem;
    privates.start = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(privates.el).getPropertyValue("top"),
            privates.RADIX);

    privates.status = 'down';
    privates.end = privates.start + offset;
    privates.current = privates.start;
    privates.id = null;

    (function next() {
        if ((privates.status === 'down') && (privates.current < privates.end)) {
            privates.current += privates.GRAN_DIST;
            privates.el.style.top = privates.current + privates.UNITS;
            if (!privates.id) {
                privates.id = setInterval(next, privates.GRAN_TIME);
            }
        } else if ((privates.status === 'down') && (privates.current === privates.end)) {
            privates.status = 'up';
            Priv.resetInterval(privates);
            setTimeout(next, delay);
        } else if ((privates.status === 'up') && (privates.current > privates.start)) {
            privates.current -= privates.GRAN_DIST;
            privates.el.style.top = privates.current + privates.UNITS;
            if (!privates.id) {
                privates.id = setInterval(next, privates.GRAN_TIME);
            }
        } else if ((privates.status === 'up') && (privates.current === privates.start)) {
            Priv.resetInterval(privates);
            callback();
        }
    }());
};
```

Comment: Crockford has some ideosyncratic ideas about Javascript, and JSLint implements them.

Comment: , but in this case I think it might be a bug, I could see him require the prefix on all window properties maybe.  Maybe it missing setInterval is a bug.

Comment: When I run your code through JSLint it complains `window was used before it was defined` for `window.getComputedStyle`, and `setInterval  was used before it was defined`. If I remove `window.`, it complains that `getComputedStyle was used before it was defined`.

Comment: maybe you don't have the options set correctly.  I did not post the entire file. `/*jslint
  browser: true,
  vars:    true,
  forin:   true,
  nomen:   true,
  ass:     true,
  eqeq:    true,
  unparam: true
*/`

Comment: Yeah, that was it. But there are other global functions it doesn't complain about: `setTimeout`, `isNaN`, `encodeURIComponent` are the ones I tried. It seems more like there's something about `getComputed Style` that triggers the warning. I suspect it has a list of known global functions, and `getComputedStyle` isn't in it.